# python, dictionaries how to get the first value of the first key

Tags: python

So basically I have a dictionary with x and y values and I want to be able to get only the x value of the first coordinate and only the y value of the first coordinate and then the same with the second coordinate and so on, so that I can use it in an if-statement.

Comment: Show an example for your dictionary. What's it's structure? How are the keys named?

Comment: Please try to include all necessary code to reproduce your problem. [mcve]

Comment: i added my code

Comment: You should not shadow the built-in keyword `dict` as it is the introduction to completely avoidable and needless headaches.  Use a different name like `dct` instead.

Comment: Actually I'm not even sure what `create_world` is supposed to accomplish here... it's not `return`ing anything nor is it mutating any passed objects.  What is `wereld` in context of `add_coordinates`? If this is in fact your actual code you have more issues than getting values from a dictionary.

Comment: I changed it, I had to translate it that's why, but I don't think that I have that many problems, everything is working fine I just need to know how to take the first x co of the first key i add to the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

if the values are ordered in columns just use

> `x=your_variable[:,0] y=your_variable[:,1]`

i think

Comment: what do you mean by your variable?

Comment: your list or array

Comment: i get an error saying unhashable type

Comment: use numpy lib,,, write 'np.array(your_variable[:,0])'

Comment: your dictionary  data should be aligned